# Proving $\cos 3$ is irrational without heavy theorems in transcendental number theory

Tags: number-theory

It is known that $e, \cos 1, \sin 1$ are irrational numbers, and it can be easily proved without using any heavy machinery in transcendental number theory (such as Gelfond-Schneider theorem). For example, to prove that $e$ is irrational, we consider its series expansion
$$
e = 1+ \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!} + \cdots.
$$
If $e = \frac{p}{q}$ for some $p, q\in \mathbb{Z}$, then we multiply $q!$ on both sides and we get 
$$
p(q-1)! = N + \sum_{j=q+1}^{\infty} \frac{q!}{j!}
$$
where 
$$
N = \sum_{j=0}^{q} \frac{q!}{j!}
$$
is an integer. Then we can prove that the *error term* 
$$
\sum_{j=q+1}^{\infty} \frac{q!}{j!}
$$
is strictly smaller than 1, which gives a contradiction. Same argument can be applied to $\cos 1$ and $\sin 1$.

However, in case of $\cos 3$, we can't apply the same argument since the error term can't be bounded by $1$. Since $\cos 3 = 4\cos^{3}1 - 3\cos 1$, we may try to prove that $\cos 1$ can't be a root of rational cubic polynomial, which doesn't seem easy to prove.

Comment: Maybe you could adapt the method (which is some way short of G-S) of proving that $e^n$ is irrational for $n\in\Bbb N$?

Comment: How about trying to see if one can prove the analogous error term should be _strictly between_ two integers?

Comment: A 1 is missing in the expansion of e.

Comment: @gpassante I edited, thanks!

Comment: @The_Sympathizer I also thought about it, but I have no idea how to proceed in that way.

Comment: @Paul Isn’t it hard to prove transcendence of $\cos 1$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a simple proof that $\cos(1)$ is transcendental?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3422451/is-there-a-simple-proof-that-cos1-is-transcendental)